# Rearrange the order of keys in NSDictionary for crypto hash match of entire dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, hash

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a payload in the below format.

//Ordered Payload - observed at the receiving end.

{
  "xx":"First",
  "yy":"Second",
  "11":{
         "xx1":"innerVal1",
         "xx2":"innerVal2"

```
   }
```

}

Since NSDictionary is basically unordered, it kinda shuffles this key - value pairs with in the dictionary when viewing on console of Xcode.

The same payload order is captured(as above ordered dict) when making a POST request at the api proxy end.

To ensure that the payload isn't tampered I need to do a hash(HMAC) of the payload and attach it in the request. The problem is that when I hash the payload (converting NSDict to JSON string) as is unordered just as NSDict property, and it won't match at the proxy when it tries to compares the hash with that of the ordered payload received in the request.

When I do a 'po' on NSDictionary this is what I see and its the same every time.

//unOrdered Payload - observed at the sending end.

//observe that the key holding a dictionary is always seen first in the dictionary followed by the other key-value pairs.

{
  "11":{
         "xx2":"innerVal2",
         "xx1":"innerVal1"
       },
  "yy":"Second",
  "xx":"First"
}

Is there any way I could make sure that my hash's are the same when the payload is not tampered ?

I understand its clearly not so possible, I think its worth giving a shot. 
I have come up with other logic to use directly the key-value pairs for hashing and not the complete dictionary.

But since the payload format could be changing over the time, I don't want to keep changing the code at both client and server side for it.

Appreciate your time to help me find a solution for it.

Comment: Any luck on this from client side?

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the JSON data prior to sending, not the dictionary.

1. Convert the `NSDictionary` to JSON data with `NSJSONSerialization` method: `dataWithJSONObject`.
2. Hash the JSON data.
3. Sent the JSON data and hash.

On the server side:

1. Hash the received JSON data
2. Compare the computed hash to the received hash value

If hasing the JSON data is not an option just hash all the keys and values together or perhaps just the values if the keys are not an issue. Sort the keys and use that key order for hashing order. 
Or just use SSL.

Comment: Well that sounds feasible but the problem is to validate if the payload has been tampered or not. The actual scheme at the server is to receive payload create a timestamped hash and compare it. I shouldn't be sending JSON data and hash along with payload.

Comment: Isn't the payload JSON? Well, just hash together all the values and keys on each side, see updated answer.

Comment: How are you going to verify the hash on the server-side? I think your validation problem is deeper than getting a hash on each side.